# Insert A Record Into A Nested Array

Tags: mongodb

I have a BSON record in my mongo collection as follows:

```
db.item.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5635194b6929067972b85c"),
    "name" : "car",
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "color" : "blue",
            "qty" : 10
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to update the record in the collection using upsert semantics as follows:

```
db.item.update({"name" : "car", "attributes.color" : "red"}, { "$push" : {"attributes.0" : {"color" : "red", "qty": 10}}}, {upsert : true})
```

The idea being that if there is no record in the attributes array with color red then it should append that record in the array. But when I run the command I get the following:

```
db.item.update({"name" : "car", "attributes.color" : "red"}, { "$push" : {"attributes.0" : {"color" : "red", "qty": 10}}}, {upsert : true})
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5635c74b6929067972b874")
})
> db.item.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5635194b6929067972b85c"),
    "name" : "car",
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "color" : "blue",
            "qty" : 10
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5635c74b6929067972b874"),
    "attributes" : {
        "color" : "red",
        "0" : [
            {
                "color" : "red",
                "qty" : 10
            }
        ]
    },
    "name" : "car"
}
```

What query do I need to run to just append the record to the nested array?

Comment: Reading around the various SO posts, it seems that upsert is at the document level not the embedded document level which is why this is so problematic and difficult to get right. It's ridiculous that something so conceptually trivial is so complicated in Mongodb